# Python: unpack android backup?

Tags: android, python, backup, tar, zlib

I'd like to unpack an Android backup file using python.

According to http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/06/unpacking-android-backups.html an unencryted adb file can be decompressed using

```
dd if=mybackup.ab bs=24 skip=1|openssl zlib -d > mybackup.tar
```

and

```
tar xvf mybackup.tar
```

Can these can be done in python? Python has `zlib`, `gzip` and `tarfile`, which seem as if they should be usable. In any event, if they can be done, how to?

Would `tarfile.open('filename.tar', 'r:')` work for the second step?

I'm on windows, btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file is not too big for everything to fit comfortably in memory, after the needed imports from the standard library:

```
with open('mybackup.ab', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(24)  # skip 24 bytes
    data = f.read()  # read the rest

tarstream = zlib.decompress(data)
tf = tarfile.open(fileobj=io.BytesIO(tarstream))
```

Now in `tf` you have a `TarFile` instance as documented in https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile-objects , so you can e.g get a list of its contents, extract one or more members, &c.

If the backup is too big for all these bits to fit comfortably in memory, you can of course write any or all of the intermediate results to disk; but if it's small enough keeping everything in memory should result in faster execution.

Comment: Because my Android backup file is encrypted, I had to make use the Python library https://github.com/bluec0re/android-backup-tools to decrypt and decompress my backup database.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the .ab file format has a (UTF-8 text) header on it that can be variable length, with standard CRLF pairs for end-of-line.  It isn't always 24 bytes.  The last line of the header is always empty and the binary archive data starts right after.  This means you should scan from the start of the archive file until you find a CRLFCRLF sequence, then the archive data per se begins with the next byte thereafter.

If you actually parse the header, it says whether the data is compressed [it's technically optional] and what the encryption parameters are if any, and so on.

The archive format itself in a .ab file is essentially **tar** with modern **ustar**/**pax** extensions, though with metadata-encoded file naming rather than strictly physical paths, etc.  In particular there will often be **pax** extended header blocks, not just old-style **tar** file headers, in order to support large files or long filenames.  If you're trying to create .ab files there are also some ordering requirements between manifest metadata files for each app's data and the files themselves, but lexical ordering should take care of that for you.  Be sure to look at the archive construction code in Android's BackupManagerService.java file for reference.